# Application Crashes on Cancelling Message Composer Or Mail Composer view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My application is is landscape mode. I am presenting the activity view controller in landscape only with the following lines of code:-

```
 NSArray *shrArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", KHL_SHARE_TEXT], nil];
UIActivityViewController *shareUIAVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems: shrArr applicationActivities: nil];
if([shareUIAVC respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:forKey:)])
{
    [shareUIAVC setValue:KHL_SHARE_MAIL_TEXT forKey:@"subject"];
}

if([shareUIAVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)])
{
    shareUIAVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.menuButton;
    shareUIAVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.menuButton.bounds;
}
[self presentViewController:shareUIAVC animated: YES completion: nil];
```

The Activity view controller opens in landscape and on choosing either message or mail and either sending or cancelling the message or mail composer, the app crashes with the following logs.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation '(7)' must match a supported interface orientation: 'landscapeLeft, landscapeRight'!'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186f991b8 0x1859d055c 0x186f99100 0x18cf44670 0x18d810428 0x18d19abf0 0x18d1be6c8 0x18cf7b1bc 0x18cf21f14 0x18d1bd920 0x18cf21a48 0x18d7f672c 0x18d7f6a64 0x18d067bdc 0x18d7d5ad4 0x1974b498c 0x1974cbad8 0x186f9f150 0x186e91eac 0x188b6f92c 0x188b6f798 0x188b48058 0x18d0d1684 0x18d126664 0x18a293e10 0x18a26b4c4 0x18a292a68 0x18a293488 0x186f460c0 0x186f43cf0 0x186f44180 0x186e722b8 0x188926198 0x18ceb97fc 0x18ceb4534 0x100143930 0x185e555b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2017-06-01 16:36:17.423693

As suggesting from various sources here , I added the following code too, but that does'nt work either

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in appdelegate

```
 - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
    {
        //self.isMailController enable while activityViewcontroller appears and disable while it dissmissed.
        if(self.isMailController){
// you can check multiple viewcontroller
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; // if your mail viewcontroller it will display on portrait
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
```